# Why are identical characters from different alphabets encoded differently?

Tags: unicode, fonts, character-encoding

For example the Latin P and the Cyrillic Р. I have never come across a font that renders these characters differently, so why the duplicates? Duplicate punctuations don't exist for Latin and Cyrillic, so why duplicate letters?

Furthermore, why would a font designer want to encode identical characters to look differently? Isn't consistency important in a font?

Comment: You mean why doesn't the Latin alphabet just have a bunch of holes and you're supposed to look up the missing letters from Cyrillic and Greek?

Answer (score -1):

Font design doesn't care about Unicode code points. Thanks to font character maps, the same glyph can be assigned to multiple code points. (Similarly, the same code point can be serviced by multiple glyphs, e.g. for contextual substitutions.)

Comment: Good to know, but it doesn't answer the question of why there are separate code points to begin with.